# Recursively form an interger sum of all digit characters in a string?

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to recursively go through a string, and add up all the digits I come across and return the final answer. In my head, I feel that my return call should be the value of the integer I just came across + a recursive call to my function, only one place further in the string this time. Would anyone be willing to push me in the right direction here? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have a good handle on it, what's the hangup?

Comment: Post your code for help.

Comment: Headed to bed so I'll check this tomorrow, but my initial hangup was how to recursively call the function so that it advanced a place in the string. I wasn't sure how to do that without an iterator or counter defined outside of the function. But I just learned about substr which I did not know existed, so I believe that will help with my issue. If I am still struggling I'll post some code, thanks!

Comment: @JimmyBlundell Are you not allowed to use an iterator (or a raw pointer)? Another common way to do it is to pass the counter (i.e. the index) as an argument, with default value 0.

Comment: @leewz I may be able to do it that way, it's open to interpretation as far as that is concerned. I was just hoping to do it so that I just needed to pass in the string. If I were to use an iterator or pointer, wouldn't I still have to initialize it outside of the function for it to work properly?

Comment: The *proper* return value should be `unsigned`...

Comment: @Rusk The *proper* solution should not abort on non-digits ... :p

Comment: @JimmyBlundell You can use a default value that you check for, or you can write two functions: one that acts recursively, and one that initializes the arguments. I use both of those tools in my toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Since you formulated what to do allready ...

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

#define very

very very unsigned unsigned long long digit_sum(std::string_view sv)
{
    if (sv.empty())
        return 0;

    int ch = static_cast<char unsigned>(sv[0]);    // make sure not to pass 
    return ( std::isdigit(ch) ? ch - '0' : 0 )  // negative values to isdigit()
        + digit_sum(sv.substr(1));
}

int main()
{
    char const *a{ "123a456" };
    std::cout << a << ": " << digit_sum(a) << '\n';  // 21

    char const *b{ "abc" };
    std::cout << b << ": " << digit_sum(b) << '\n';  // 0

    char const *c{ "0" };
    std::cout << c << ": " << digit_sum(c) << '\n';  // 0

    char const *d{ "" };
    std::cout << d << ": " << digit_sum(d) << '\n';  // 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more straight forward C solution (without static casts).
It assumes an `atoi` behavior where first non digit character means decimal string terminated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int sum(const char *s)
{
    if (s ==  NULL) return 0;
    if (s[0] ==  0) return 0;
    if (s[0] > '9') return 0;
    if (s[0] < '0') return 0;

    return (s[0]-'0')+sum(s+1);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *x1 = "7934";
    char *x2 = "48d6";
    char *x3 = "appp";

    printf("%d\n",sum(x1));
    printf("%d\n",sum(x2));
    printf("%d\n",sum(x3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long long digit_sum(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s.empty())
        return 0;

    const char c = s.at(0);

    const int i = (c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5'
                            || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9'
                  ) ? atoi(c) : 0;

    if (s.size() == 1)
        return i;
    else
        return i + digit_sum(s.substr(1));
}
```